# htmlspecialchars behavior on php variable

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I do know that `htmlspecialchars` should only be used to output to screen.But I'm having some trouble to understand it behavior of escaping malicious data.

When I print PHP variable that contains `htmlspecialchars used data` is escape properly.But when I use that variable `inside another variable`,and print the second variable,it doesn't escape special characters.

Please look at the code for better understanding

**does escape**

```
$page_owner.="<div id='pg_owner_$userx' class='now'><div id='user_img_holder' ><img src='account/".htmlspecialchars($userx)."/".htmlspecialchars($image)."' id='user_img' ><div id=''><b>".htmlspecialchars($busi_title)."</b></div></div></div>";
echo $page_owner;
```

**doesn't escape**

```
$all.="<div class='hold_indi_samesrc'>".$page_owner.".<div style='float:left;'>".$alu."</div></div>";
echo $all;
```

when I `echo $all`,it doesn't escape `special character` that is in `$page_owner`.

Why is it happening?Is there any way to work around with this issue?

**Edit**

`second code block` contain `$page_owner` which is in `first code block`.

When I echo `$page_owner`(for testing purpose),I get `$userx`,`$busi_title` 's specialchars escaped.But as I need to have `$alu` and `$page_owner` inside `$all`.When I echo `$all`,I cannot get `$userx`,`$image`,`$busi_title` 's special characters escaped.Is it even possible.How can I do that?

Please help,if you can.

Comment: And where is `htmlspecialchars` used in the second one ?

Comment: I used that on `$page_owner`.why `$busi_title` is not escaped when I echo `$all`

Comment: Could I make my point clear?data that is in `$page_owner` contains `htmlspecialchars`.Why don't I get escaped data from `$page_owner`,when I echo `$all`

Comment: I think you should make a better small example for yourself, to see if you can really reproduce this behaviour outside your main code base. I think you will discover you cannot. What I mean: The error is somewhere else.

Comment: I couldn't get your point.What'd u mean by `reproduce this behaviour outside main code base`?Did you mean,it's not possible the way,I'm looking for?

Comment: You're going to have to show us **how** you used `htmlspecialchars` in the second example. You did of course write it back, as in `$page_owner = htmlspecialchars( $page_owner );` etc ?

Comment: If I had to make a guess OP embedded the string htmlspecialchars literally in the source string? But as everyone else pointed out, expand your "Doesn't escape" example to include the actual htmlspecialchars statements. This is an incomplete example.

Comment: @adeneo pls have a look at edited question.I think,you would get my point then.

Comment: @Evert question edited.Pls have a look

Comment: @adeneo .if I use `htmlspecialchars($page_owner)` that would escape all divs and img tags.I just need to escape variable that is in `$page_owner`.Your help would be really appreciated

Comment: I just tested it, and it works perfectly fine for me when setting up a minimal example. Why you would `htmlspecialchars` in HTML attributes is beyond me though ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me.I'm using database fetched data.By the way,I'm using  `htmlspecialchars` inside specific html attribute.is it open to XSS that way?

Comment: It's only open to XSS if you don't validate the data **before** you stick in your database

Comment: If you look at my profile,you would see lots of my questions was about security.Most of the answers emphasize about not mangle data before inserting into database.They suggested to take data as it is inputted.But anyway,I really do respect your opinion as well.

Comment: You still didn't post an example we can actually reproduce the edit doesn't help. Post a few lines of code that actually _show_ the problem. Including the output you want, and the actual output you're getting.